# Help analyzing repeated measures categorical data

Tags: repeated-measures, categorical-data

This is my first post. I have the following data set-up: I asked 331 subjects about whether or not they would take a drug to enhance the following four domains/abilities: Cognition, Mood, Sex, and Physical appearance. For each domain/ability, subjects had to choose one of three options: 'No', 'Maybe', or 'Yes'. My goal is to determine whether subjects were more willing to enhance one or more of these four domains. In other words, is willingness to enhance equal across these four domains, or are some of them more likely to be enhanced than others.

This is like a 4 x 3 contingency table, but I cannot use a chi-square as the assumption of independence of observations is clearly violated - each subject provided responses for each of the four domains.

Here is what I have considered thus far. I could treat the response variable as a numeric variable (i.e., coding 'No' as 0, 'Maybe' as 1, and 'Yes' as 2), and then doing a Friedman's test or even better the rank test from Brunner, Domhof, and Langer (2002). I think this would work, but I imagine there will be a lot of ties (i.e., there are 3 options for 4 domains, so for every subject there will be at least 1 tie in their set of rankings). My understanding is that the Brunner, Domhof, and Langer (2002) methods can handle ties, however. I am also a bit concerned about treating such truncated ordinal data in this way.

I have also considered performing the Stuart-Maxwell test for each pair of two-way comparisons (e.g., compare the No, Maybe, and Yes responses for Cognition and Mood, Cognition and Sex, etc). I must admit that before today, I knew nothing about this test, and my only knowledge has been acquired via google (not so great).

I would greatly appreciate any advice on how I can analyze these data (and yes, I wish I would have used a response scale that had more options, or even a likert scale!)

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: Sounds to me like a nonlinear mixed model.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I do not have much experience with these types of models, would you mind providing a bit more information/context on what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: They are complex models designed to deal with dependent data. Also known as multilevel models. In place of $Y = X\beta + e$ they use $Y = X\beta + z\Gamma + e$. In `R` see `nlme` (e.g.) in `SAS` see PROC GLIMMIX.